# Strange Click Event Bubble on iPhone safari that it stop before bubbling to document.body

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari, mobile-website

I have bind a click event as document.body.onclick = function(){alert("aaa")};

It do good both on android or chrome on IOS whatever element I click.
But it does not trigger on iPhone safari while click the elements except a and img element.

But it can bubble to body while binding the touchstart event.

At last, I have to add to div(#main) to contain all my elements, and then bind the delegate object on this div.

document.querySelector("#main").onclick = function(){alert("aaa")}

So I am wandering why the onclick event stops before it bubble to body.

Answer (score 10):

I know this is quite old, but I still managed to dig it up when I ran into the very same issue.

In short, mouse events in iOS Safari do not bubble up to the `document.body` unless iOS Safari thinks the event target is a clickable element.

Clickable element is one of the following:

> 1. The target element of the event is a link or a form field.
> 2. The target element, or any of its ancestors up to **but not including** the `<body>`, has an explicit event handler set for any of the mouse events. This event handler may be an empty function.
> 3. The target element, or any of its ancestors up to and including the document has a cursor: pointer CSS declarations.

(Quoted from [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2014/02/mouse_event_bub.html), emphasis mine.)

Possible fixes include:

- Add `cursor: pointer` to any element that does not fit the description.
- Add a no-op event handler to the target.
- Handle the clicks one level below `document.body`.

Comment: This worked. I'd liked to add a strange behavior I noticed: If I remote debug Safari (IOS) and set a breakpoint on touch events, it works fine (the event bubbles), but if I disable the breakpoint, it doesn't.

Comment: That does sound like something Safari iOS would do, to be honest. :D