# CSS React Transition

Tags: css, reactjs

i have a sidebar with css transition. its works true when its open but it is not works when i close sidenav.

i have tried -leave animation but its not works.

```
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup
     transitionName="example"
     transitionAppear={true}
     transitionLeave={true}
     transitionAppearTimeout={600}
     transitionLeaveTimeout={300}
     >
     <div key={"slidebar"} className="chatBar">
         <Tab />
     </div>
</ReactCSSTransitionGroup>


.example-appear {
    width: 0;
    transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.example-appear.example-appear-active {
    width: 17%;
}

.example-leave {
    width: 17%;
    transition: width 0.9s ease-in-out
}

.example-leave.example-leave-active {
    width: 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried?
 .example-leave.example-leave-active {
      width: 0;
  }

Comment: yes i had tried... its not works

Comment: It seems ok. Would you please deploy to some JSFiddle so that others can help to find the problem online?

Comment: It solved. i define ReactCSSTransitionGroup in a wrong place. thank you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/lemanslmi/f15uvdxj/ here is my code that solved.thanks to @Joy.