# stop handleBlur from doing anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, formik

In my Formik form, when I click on the search button, a list of items is rendered (UsersFoundList). This **list is outside the form** and each item in the list has a button of its own.

When I click on  any of those buttons from the list for the first time, they don't work. Instead, the **handleBlur of my form is triggered** and since the input field is empty, an error messages starts showing under the input field. So, the button doesn't do what it's supposed to do in the first attempt. I tested the handleBlur by writing a console log into it.

This error should only show up when I am trying to submit the form again. Not when I click on anything else.

```
const [showFlatList, setShowFlatList] = useState(false);

    const handleSubmitForm = (
    values: FormValues,
    helpers: FormikHelpers<FormValues>,
  ) => {
    console.log('hello', values.input)
    setShowFlatList(true);
    helpers.resetForm();
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View >
          <Formik
            initialValues={initialValues}
            onSubmit={handleSubmitForm}
            validationSchema={addRelationValidationSchema}>
            {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values }) => (
              <View style={styles.searchFieldContainer}>
                <View style={styles.form}>
                  <FieldInput
                    handleChange={handleChange}
                    handleBlur={handleBlur}
                    value={values.input}
                    fieldType="input"
                    icon="user"
                    placeholderText="E-Mail oder Telefonnummer oder Name"
                  />
                  <ErrorMessage
                    name="input"
                    render={(msg) => <ErrorText errorMessage={msg} />}
                  />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                  <NewButton buttonText="Suchen" onPress={handleSubmit} />
                </View>
              </View>
            )}
          </Formik>
        </View>
                <View style={styles.listHolder}>
          {showFlatList && (
            <UsersFoundList/>
          )}
        </View>
    </View>
  );
```

If you run the **codesandbox** on a phone, you can see the problem:

https://snack.expo.io/@nhammad/jealous-beef-jerky

I need to stop the handleBlur from doing anything. If I click on the a button from the list, it should work on the very first attempt instead of triggering the handleBlur. The problem still exists even if I add `validateOnBlur=false`. In this case, the error message doesn't show up but the button still doesn't work on the first attempt.

The button that I click has a separate function. and this button is outside the form so it should do what it's originally supposed to do instead of doing anything in the onBlur(in the sandbox: it's just printing).

Comment: note that handleBlur is only called whenever I click on INSIDE the userFoundEntry item. It's not triggered if I click outside it (at least from what I observed).

Comment: `onBlur` is the default validation for Formik. It will trigger before the `onClick` event you have in your other button. Why it prevents the other event to be called? I don't know. There's a workaround though. You can trigger the `onMouseDown` event in your button before the `onBlur` in your field. I mean, onMouseDown occurs before the blur (and we can't say the same for onMouseUp, that one is similar to onClick). See: https://github.com/formium/formik/issues/2062

Answer (score 1):

`onBlur` is the default behavior using Formik. It will trigger if you were focusing a field, no matter if you click on something outside the form or not.

And `onBlur` will trigger before any `onClick` event.

There are a couple of workarounds though.

1. Use onMouseDown (& onKeyDown) instead of onClick

Basically, `onMouseDown` will be called before `onBlur`.
See an example implementation here: https://github.com/formium/formik/issues/2062

```
<a
    href="#back-to-previous"
    onMouseDown={onClick}
    onKeyUp={(e) => {
      e.key === 'Enter' && onClick(e);
    }}
>
```

`onKeyDown` is there for accesibility, and you should check that is the Enter key the one being pressed, not just any key.

2. Override onBlur and call formik onBlur conditionally

This may sound hacky, but it could fit some scenarios.

Example:

```
onBlur={(e) => {
  const wasLinkClicked = e.relatedTarget && e.relatedTarget.tagName === 'A';
   if (!wasLinkClicked) {
      handleBlur(e);
  }
}}
```

That code checks wether you are clicking a link. In your case, you could write a different logic: "was the clicked button inside the form?".

Answer (score 0):

In your `FieldInput` definition you are calling the function when `onBlur` every render.

To prevent that from happening you can use an arrow function, which React will render only on blur

```
onBlur={(fieldType) => handleBlur(fieldType)}
```

You can find a more extensive explanation in the React.js Docs:

https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html

Comment: Do you mean fieldType? I have already tried ```onBlur={()=>handleChange(fieldType)}```but it doesn't work. The button from the list still doesn't work on the first click.

Comment: You are trying to pass parameters, (fieldType) => handledChange(fieldType)

Comment: The type script expect an event as the first argument so (event, fieldType) => handleBlur(_event, fieldType) might cover you there

Comment: Even with this, the handleBlur is still called when I click on the button/UserFoundENtry.

Comment: When you click on a button, you would like that onBlur will trigger. This is the expectetion from onBlur event. You need to handle that in the function

Comment: No, I want that onBlur should not trigger. The button that I click has a separate function. and this button is outside the form so it should do what it's originally supposed to do instead of doing anything in the onBlur(in the sandbox: it's just printing). Have you looked at the condesandbox? Maybe it will give you a clearer picture.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into it?

Comment: I did. But you have changed the question to resolved other bugs in your code. My initial answer was the answer to your initial question. The question is too broad and unclear. I am sorry but I don't think that I would like to debug this code to perfection

Comment: What does "you are calling the function when onBlur every render" is supposed to mean? Writting `onBlur={handleBlur}` and `onBlur={(e) => handleBlur(e)}` is exactly the same, just less verbose.