# Unit testing React click outside component

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Using the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42234988/766958) to solve clicking outside of a component:

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClickOutside);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClickOutside);
}

setWrapperRef(node) {
    this.wrapperRef = node;
}

handleClickOutside(event) {
    if (this.wrapperRef && !this.wrapperRef.contains(event.target)) {
        this.props.actions.something() // Eg. closes modal
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to unit test the unhappy path so the alert isn't run, what i've got so far:

```
it('Handles click outside of component', () => {
  props = {
    actions: {
      something: jest.fn(),
    }
  }
  const wrapper = mount(
    <Component {... props} />,
  )
  expect(props.actions.something.mock.calls.length).toBe(0)

  // Happy path should trigger mock

  wrapper.instance().handleClick({
    target: 'outside',
  })

  expect(props.actions.something.mock.calls.length).toBe(1)  //true

  // Unhappy path should not trigger mock here ???

  expect(props.actions.something.mock.calls.length).toBe(1)
})
```

I've tried:

- sending through `wrapper.html()`
- `.find`ing a node and sending through (doesn't mock a `event.target`)
- `.simulate`ing `click` on an element inside (doesn't trigger event listener)

I'm sure i'm missing something small but I couldn't find an example of this anywhere.

Comment: you might want to try changing your 'outside click'  detection logic to handle onBlur event on some root element of the component: https://gist.github.com/pstoica/4323d3e6e37e8a23dd59

Comment: Though the selected answer is correct I ended up offloading this logic to the react-onclickoutside library - https://github.com/Pomax/react-onclickoutside

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme'
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

it('Should not call action on click inside the component', () => {
  const map = {}

  document.addEventListener = jest.fn((event, cb) => {
    map[event] = cb
  })

  const props = {
    actions: {
      something: jest.fn(),
    }
  }

  const wrapper = mount(<Component {... props} />)

  map.mousedown({
    target: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(wrapper.instance()),
  })

  expect(props.actions.something).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

The solution from [this](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/426) enzyme issue on github.

Comment: wasn't the opposite asked? how do you detect a click outside of the component in a unit test?

Comment: I think just changing the target to something like `document.body` would complete this answer.

Answer (score 2):

The selected answer did not cover the else path of `handleClickOutside`

I added mousedown event on ref element to trigger else path of `handleClickOutside`

```js
import { mount } from 'enzyme'
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

it('Should not call action on click inside the component', () => {
  const map = {}

  document.addEventListener = jest.fn((event, cb) => {
    map[event] = cb
  })

  const props = {
    actions: {
      something: jest.fn(),
    }
  }
  //test if path of handleClickOutside
  const wrapper = mount(<Component {... props} />)

  map.mousedown({
    target: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(wrapper.instance()),
  })

  //test else path of handleClickOutside
  const refWrapper = mount(<RefComponent />)

  map.mousedown({
    target: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(refWrapper.instance()),
  })

  expect(props.actions.something).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the case/solution where the usage of `ReactDOM.findDOMNode` can be avoided. Treat the following example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

const initFireEvent = () => {
  const map = {};

  document.addEventListener = jest.fn((event, cb) => {
    map[event] = cb;
  });

  document.removeEventListener = jest.fn(event => {
    delete map[event];
  });

  return map;
};

describe('<ClickOutside />', () => {
  const fireEvent = initFireEvent();
  const children = <button type="button">Content</button>;

  it('should call actions.something() when clicking outside', () => {
    const props = {
      actions: {
       something: jest.fn(),
     }
    };

    const onClick = jest.fn();

    mount(<ClickOutside {...props}>{children}</ClickOutside>);
    fireEvent.mousedown({ target: document.body });

    expect(props.actions.something).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });

  it('should NOT call actions.something() when clicking inside', () => {
    const props = {
      actions: {
       something: jest.fn(),
     }
    };

    const wrapper = mount(
      <ClickOutside onClick={onClick}>{children}</ClickOutside>,
    );

    fireEvent.mousedown({
      target: wrapper.find('button').instance(),
    });

    expect(props.actions.something).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Versions:

```
"react": "^16.8.6",
"jest": "^25.1.0",
"enzyme": "^3.11.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing just dispatchEvent on body

```js
  mount(<MultiTagSelect {...props} />);
window.document.body.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
```

Answer (score -3):

Use `sinon` to track the `handleClickOutside` is called or not. By the way, I just now released our project where I need this unit-test in the `Nav` component . Indeed when you click outside, all submenus should be closed.

```
import sinon from 'sinon';
import Component from '../src/Component';

it('handle clicking outside', () => {
     const handleClickOutside = sinon.spy(Component.prototype, 'handleClickOutside');
     const wrapper = mount(
         <div> 
           <Component {... props} />
           <div><a class="any-element-outside">Anylink</a></div>
         </div>
      ); 

      wrapper.find('.any-element-outside').last().simulate('click'); 
      expect(handleClickOutside.called).toBeTruthy(); 
      handleClickOutside.restore(); 
})
```

Comment: As far as I can tell this tests that `handleClickOutside` has been called, but does not test the if condition of whether it's contained in the `wrapperRef` or not?

Comment: This won't work. The way it's written you're looking inside the component for a class that exists outside of the component. I guess you could import a component that is in the view that is outside the component to test the click on, but feels like there should be a better way.