# Unit testing React click outside component using Jest and react testing library

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I found this implementation here but its using enzyme.

[Unit testing React click outside component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45046728/unit-testing-react-click-outside-component)

Adding an event to window does not work either:

```
window.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log('click on window');
    });
```

Has anyone came across this issue above using jest and "@testing-library/react"?

Comment: Did you try to run `fireEvent.click(document)`?

Comment: That worked. Thanks @GiorgioPolvara-Gpx

Answer (score 35, accepted):

as @Giorgio mentioned:

```
fireEvent.click(document)

//or

userEvent.click(document.body);
```

Answer (score 21):

I'd like to provide an up-to-date answer which follows the same principle as what @eduardomoroni proposed.
The `fireEvent` hasn't worked for me and so I've managed to achieve it with the `userEvent` api.

```
userEvent.click(document.body);
```

Also, as typescript complains `document` cannot be passed to the click event handler. Instead, the `body` is a better solution.

> Argument of type 'Document' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TargetElement'.

Comment: Please explain where does the mysterious `userEvent` comes from

Comment: fireEvent.click(document.body) worked for me

Comment: @vsync  It comes from the https://testing-library.com/docs/ecosystem-user-event/

Comment: This works! Thank you so much :)

Comment: for me, I had to do `fireEvent.mouseDown(document);`

Comment: For me, I needed :


const [_, bd] = screen.getAllByRole('presentation');
await userEvent.click(bd);