# @testing-library/React : Clicking outside of component not working

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, dialog, react-testing-library, testing-library

I'm using react testing library to test my component built with FluentUI.

Here is link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-borg-2tqmj?file=/src/App.spec.js

The code is basically a pasted snippet of the example code of `Dialog` component from FluentUI docs site. The behavior that I'm testing is:

1. User opens the dialog
2. User clicks outside of the dialog
3. `onDimiss` prop of the component should be fired.

It works when I'm playing with it manually however it seems that I failed to simulate a click outside of the component with testing library.

I tried using `userEvent.click(document.body)` as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56978283/unit-testing-react-click-outside-component-using-jest-and-react-testing-library) but got no luck

Does anyone has any idea how to make test work?

Comment: `this post` link has the same codesandbox url

Comment: no problem, let me know if my answer works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not working because the Dialog component is not listening for the `onClick` event on the `body`, so what you need to do in this case is to find the actual element that is being clicked, observing the dom you'll find that the overlay is a div with some overlay classes on it.

```
        <div
          class="ms-Modal is-open ms-Dialog root-94"
          role="document"
        >
          <div
            aria-hidden="true"
            class="ms-Overlay ms-Overlay--dark root-99"
          />
```

The problem now is to find a way to select it. Unfortunately, you cannot select elements in RTL by their className, so you need to use another selector; in this case, we can get the parent element by the role and then access the first child.

```
    const onDismiss = jest.fn();
    const { getByRole } = render(<App onDismiss={onDismiss} />);
    UserEvent.click(screen.getByText("Open Dialog"));
    const document = getByRole("document");
    UserEvent.click(document.firstChild);
    expect(onDismiss).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-joliot-tjcph?file=/src/App.spec.js

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Just curious did the test succeeded in the codesandbox url you posted? I ran your modified version of test in codesandbox directly but it still gave me the same result

Comment: @ShiCheng sorry I forgot I changed the App component code and saved it by accident, you can check again, now it is passing

Comment: I see it passing and why it's passing now. Thank you so much!