# OutsideClickHandler not firing in React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-outside-click-handler

I'm not able to get trigger the outside click handler from my component inside a React Testing Library test. Runs fine on the client, so just a testing issue.

```js
const Modal = ({ children, onClose }) => (
  <div role="presentation">
    <OutsideClickHandler onOutsideClick={onClose}>
      <div> modal stuff... </div>
    </OutsideClickHandler>
  </div>
)
```

```js
it('should close modal when clicked outside', () => {
  const mockHandleClose = jest.fn()
  render(<Modal {...props} onClose={mockHandleClose} />)
  fireEvent.click(document)
  // userEvent.click(document.body)  -- Tried this as well with no luck
  expect(mockHandleClose).toBeCalled()
})

// Test output:
//    expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled()
//    Expected number of calls: >= 1
//    Received number of calls:    0
```

I also tried targeting the "presentation" role div with no luck.

RTL Docs for testing a Modal (not OCH, but based off of their own pattern):
https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-modal

Code Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-testing-library-demo-forked-g7su2i?file=/src/__tests__/hello.js

Referenced this SO post: [Unit testing React click outside component using Jest and react testing library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56978283/unit-testing-react-click-outside-component-using-jest-and-react-testing-library)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67930922/testing-library-react-clicking-outside-of-component-not-working

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka been trying several variants of that example without luck so far. Thank you for the reference though.