# React Popin open close on outside click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have some trouble to create my `popin` with all actions linked

I use REACT JS

I have a button like this:

```
<button className="b-circle" onClick={() => this.openPopin()}></button>
<div className="u-200">Frequence</div>
{OpenPopin ? <PopinComponent />: ''}
openPopin() {
    this.setState({ openFrequency: true })
}
```

In the `popinComponent` I have a cross , when I clicked on it I need to close the `popin` and I need to detect click outside `popin` to close it too

Do you have any solution to achieve this ? What is the best way ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect click outside React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553158/detect-click-outside-react-component)

Comment: Not duplicate because my popin is open from parent component

Comment: can we see code of `PopinComponent ` component ? are you using onclickoutside hoc ?

Comment: No i don't write component now because i don't found a good solution to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You can pass prop 'clickevent' to PopinComponent and than trigger onclick on cross button from there and call this prop in that function. Something like this :

```
<button className="b-circle" onClick={this.openPopin.bind(this)}>
        </button>
        <div className="u-200">Frequence</div>
        {OpenPopin ? <PopinComponent clickevent={this.closePopin.bind(this)} />
           : ''}


  openPopin() {
    this.setState({ openFrequency: true })
  }

  closePopin(){
   this.setState({openFrequency: false})
  }
```

Now in PopinComponent you can pass this.props.clickevent in onClick -

```
<button onClick={this.props.clickevent}>Close</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, it's work and now i have the second way to close the popin it's to detect click outside popin component when it's open

Comment: Great ! But if you think my answer was useful, please click that arrow button. Thanks.