# Using 'ref' on React Styled Components is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, ref, styled-components

I am having difficulty using `ref`s with Styled Components. When I try to access them in my class methods like below, I get the following error:

> Edit.js:42 Uncaught TypeError: this.....contains is not a function

```
  constructor(props) {
    ....
    this.setWrapperRef = this.setWrapperRef.bind(this);
    this.handleClickOutside = this.handleClickOutside.bind(this);
   }
----------
  setWrapperRef = (node) => {
    this.wrapperRef = node;
  }
  handleEdit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.onEdit(this.props.id, this.state.title);
  }
----------
<Wrapper onSubmit={this.handleEdit} ref={this.setWrapperRef}>
  ...
</Wrapper>
```

I found the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553158/detect-click-outside-react-component)

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: ★ As of *styled-components* `v4` using the `ref` prop works fine → [Docs link](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#refs)

Answer (score 37):

I found the answer myself. The solution is to use `innerRef` instead of `ref` as the `ref` itself points to the Styled Component and not the DOM node.

A detailed discussion can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/617)

Comment: [This is also in the docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#refs).

Comment: For v4 and above, use the `ref` prop directly instead.

Comment: I got a warning from Emotion that the `innerRef` is going to be deprecated in the future

Comment: does it work in react native ? answer: no

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa did you find a solution on how to type ref on react-native?

Comment: Either don't uise styled, or use useRef, but with createRef, forget about it, you can thumbs up here to say you have the same problem : https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/3823

Answer (score 3):

If you extend another component in styled `ref` forwarding requires efford. so my solution was extending that component with `as` prop.

before:

```
import { useRef } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Card = styled.div``
const Block = styled(Card)``

const Component = () => {
    const ref = useRef(null);
    return <Card ref={ref} />
}
```

after:

```
import { useRef } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Card = styled.div``
const Block = styled.div``

const Component = () => {
    const ref = useRef(null);
    return <Block as={Card} ref={ref} />
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    const StyledComponent = styled.div.attrs(({ref}) => ({
      ref: ref,
    }))``

    const App = () => {
      const anyRef = useRef();

      return <StyledComponent ref={anyRef}/>
    };
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32238228)