# How to close the dialog on clicking anywhere outside the dialog using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to close the dialog on user clicking anywhere outside the dialog using typescript and react.

below is my code,

```
function Parent(){
    const [isDialogOpen, setIsDialogOpen] = React.useState(false);
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <button onClick={() => setIsDialogOpen(true)}>click me </button>
            {isDialogOpen && 
                <Dialog
                    setIsDialogOpen={setIsDialogOpen}/>
            }
        </Wrapper> 
    );
}

function Dialog ({setIsDialogOpen, items}: Props) {
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <Container_one>
                <span>title</span>
                <Description> some big description</Description>
            </Container_one>
            <Container_two>
                {items.map(item => (
                    <div
                        key={item.id}
                    />
                ))}
            </Container_two>
        </Wrapper>
    );
```

now how can i close the dialog meaning set the isDialogOpen state to false when user clicks anywhere outside the dialog using typescript and react.

could someone help me with this. thanks.

EDIT**strong text**

based on link provided i have tried below,

```
function Dialog ({setIsDialogOpen, items}: Props) {
    const dialogRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);


    React.useEffect(() => {
        const handleClickOutsideDialog = (event: any) => {
            if (
                dialogRef &&
                    !dialogRef.contains(event.target)//error here
            ) {
                alert('You clicked outside of me!');
                setIsDialogOpen(false);
               }
        };
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutsideDialog);
    }, [setIsDialogOpen]);

    
    return (
        <Wrapper ref={dialogRef}>
            <Container_one>
                <span>title</span>
                <Description> some big description</Description>
            </Container_one>
            <Container_two>
                {items.map(item => (
                    <div
                        key={item.id}
                    />
                ))}
            </Container_two>
        </Wrapper>
    );
```

In doing so, i get error "Property contains doesnt exist on type 'RefObject'

how can i fix it. also how can remove eventlistener mousedown in unmount using useeffect.

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52230381/6158118

Comment: but how can i do the same with typescript using useeffect similar to componentmount and unmount.

Comment: @Reda Mesakali: i have edited my question based on what i have tried.

Comment: `dialogRef.current && !dialogRef.current.contains(event.target)`