# Detect click on outer component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So this is my code:

```
export default ({user, showFriendsInvitations}) => {
    const handleBlur = () => {
        console.log('blur');
        setShowFriendInvitations(false);
    };
    const handleClick = () => {
        console.log(showFriendsInvitations)
        setShowFriendInvitations(!showFriendsInvitations);
    };

    const invites = user.friends.filter(f => f.accepted === false && f.blocked === true);
    return (
        <div className='inline iconBtnContainer'>
            {invites.length > 0 ?
                <div className='notificationContainer'>
                    <p>{invites.length}</p>
                </div>
                : null}

            <button className='iconBtn' onClick={handleClick}>
                 <CustomSvg/>
            </button>

            <div className='newInvitationFriendsDropdown' style={{background: 'yellow'}} onBlur={handleBlur}>
                {invites.length > 0 ?
                    <div className='newInvitationFriendsForm displayCenter'>
                        {invites.map(i => <div key={i}><FriendInvitationContainer invite={i}/></div>)}
                    </div> : <div className='newInvitationFriendsForm displayCenter'>Brak nowych zaproszeń</div>}
            </div>

            {showFriendsInvitations === true ? <FriendsInvitesContainer invites={invites}/> : null}
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

What I want to achieve: When the user clicks anywhere outside of the yellow div, (className="newInvitationFriendsDropdown") I need the `setShowFriendInvitations` to be set to false. I tried doing this with handleBlur but it registers neither `onBlur` nor `onFocus`.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Possible duplicate [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553158/detect-click-outside-react-component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553158/detect-click-outside-react-component)

Comment: Yup that solved it. Thanks!