# How to detect click outside of the React functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dom

I want to detect click outside of the React *functional* component.

Then I found the following article and implemented code accordingly.

> [Detect click outside React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553158/detect-click-outside-react-component)

But my code does not work. I understand the cause, however don't know solution.

```
import React from 'react';
import Foo from 'foo'; // <- Functional component in the node_modules

export default class extends React.PureComponent {
  private readonly refRoot = React.createRef();
  public componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.clickOutside);
  }
  public componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('click', this.clickOutside);
  }
  private clickOutside(ev: MouseEvent) {
    if (refRoot.current.contains(ev.target)) {
      console.log('clicked outside.');
    }
  }
  public render(){
    return (
      <Foo ref={this.refRoot}> // <- Doubt.
        ...
      </Foo>
    );
  }
}
```

Because [cannot use the ref attribute on function component](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#refs-and-function-components).

Maybe able to solve it by wrapping it with a `div` element, but I want to avoid complicating the stratum of the DOM any more when rendered to HTML.

What do you have any ideas?

Comment: If I understood the question correctly look into forwarding refs... https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

Comment: You want to forward the ref to the Foo component - in this case use a different name for the prop. for Example, `<Foo refParam={this.refRoot}>`, then inside Foo attach the refParam to a  dom element `<div ref={props.refParam}>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use ref inside of functional component, then rather than passing it from parent, you can use React hooks API.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Please check the above ^^

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for answer.
I'm very interested in React Hooks so I tried upgrading from v16.7.0 to v16.8.0-alpha.1.
But `useRef` was `undefined`. mmm:/

Answer (score 0):

The idea to create a ref on the DOM element rendered inside of Foo which you can do by passing it as a props which can be used in Foo

```
  <Foo innerRef={this.refRoot}> 
    ...
  </Foo>
```

Inside Foo:

```
const Foo = (props) => {
   return <div ref={props.innerRef}>{/* data here */}</div>
}
```

or you could use [`React.forwardRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) to forward Foos ref to its children

```
const Foo = React.forwardRef(props, ref) => {
   return <div ref={ref}>{/* data here */}</div>
}
```

---

Parent

```
public render(){
    return (
      <Foo ref={this.refRoot}> // <- Doubt.
        ...
      </Foo>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.
The `Foo` component is in node_modules, and cannot be edited. 
Is unavoidable that adding a dummy `div` element and wrapping it, for getting `ref`?

Comment: If Foo is in node_modules,then you can search in the library docs whether they allow a custom ref to the component using any prop. IF not than you need to add a div

Comment: The component seem not allow custom `ref`. Hmm, I give up and wrapping by `div`. 
That seems easy to implement using `airbnb/react-outside-click-handler`.
Thank you for thinking nice solutions.