# Hide autocomplete suggestion list on select dropbdown item and enter click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I 've created autocomplete suggested input field, with debounce hook, only one issue left, is close drop-down when I select item or click outside? And what is the best solution to show selected item, show it in input value on create some 'redableRenderValue'.

Current behavior : when I click enter or on item itself the drop down close and reopen again
Expected value: close on blur , close on enter and close on select item
https://codesandbox.io/s/usedebounce-ncq2n

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect click outside React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553158/detect-click-outside-react-component)

Comment: I made some changes in your code as mention in my answer below and working fine on my side, if this will not help i can share the whole `index.js` file to you, then you can make a try.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const [showSuggestions, setShowSuggestions] = useState(true); //make useState initial value to true instead of false.
```

and, delete below code from `useEffect`

```
setShowSuggestions(true); //delete this line from your code
```

also alter here:

```
<input
    type="text"
    placeholder="Find"
    onChange={e => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
    onClick={onInputClick} //add this attribute
    onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
    // onBlur={onBlur}
    value={searchTerm}
    autoFocus
/>
```

and a corresponding function to call:

```
const onInputClick = () =>{
    setShowSuggestions(true);
}
```

and Run your code.

I try it this will be working fine by doing this. Hope this will help you to.