# React TypeScript: window onClick type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What is the correct type for window.onClick, my linter is not happy with `any`

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Global } from '../globalState';
import { Dispatch, LOGGED_IN, SET_MODAL } from '../globalState';

interface PropsInterface {
  avatar: string;
  loggedIn: boolean;
  fullName: string;
}

const TopNav: React.FC<PropsInterface> = (props: PropsInterface) => {
...
window.onclick = (event: any) => {
//                        ^
//                        What is the correct type ??       
    if (
      event.target.id !== 'dropdown'
    ) {
      setState((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        dropDownStatus: false,
      }));
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For synthetic elements, you can use `React.MouseEvent`.

Answer (score 1):

This is defined in the default DOM type definition.

In the most recent version you can find this definition at [line 5903](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L5903) of the `lib.dom.d.ts`:

```
...

/**
 * Fires when the user clicks the left mouse button on the object
 * @param ev The mouse event.
 */
onclick: ((this: GlobalEventHandlers, ev: MouseEvent) => any) | null;

...
```

So the correct type would be `MouseEvent`:

```
window.onclick = (event: MouseEvent) => { }
```

If you really want to map the `id` of the target, you can do something like:

```
window.onclick = (event: MouseEvent & { target: {id: string}}) => { }
```

## TL;DR

This part doesn't answer the question, but helps to address further trouble.

You want that the dropdown closes, if anything but the dropdown was clicked, right? I think you are better of with adding a [reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to the dropdown and compare this instead of the id:

- [Detect click outside React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553158/detect-click-outside-react-component)
- https://github.com/airbnb/react-outside-click-handler
- https://medium.com/@pitipatdop/little-neat-trick-to-capture-click-outside-with-react-hook-ba77c37c7e82

Comment: I get a new error `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.ts(2339)` on `event.target.id`

Comment: @Bill: Please open another question, if you have troubles implementing off click handling, as this question is about something else.