# How to handle ref.current.contains() on a children that use ReactDOM.createPortal()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I create an app using React hooks. I have a helper function `onClickOutsideHook(ref, callback)` that trigger the `callback` when you click outside of the component that provide the `ref` using `React.useRef`:

```js
export const onClickOutsideHook = (ref, callback) => {
  // Hook get from https://stackoverflow.com/a/42234988/8583669

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const handleClickOutside = event => {
      if (ref?.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
        callback();
      }
    };
    // Bind the event listener
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    return () => {
      // Unbind the event listener on clean up
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    };
  }, [callback, ref]);
};
```

I have a component `Dropdown` that use this helper so it close when you click outside of it. This component has a `Modal` component as children that use `ReactDOM.createPortal`. I use it to render the  `Modal` in `body` so it can cover all the app screen. My `Modal` contain a button that alert a message when you clicked on it:

```js
function Modal() {
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <div
      style={{
        position: "absolute",
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        height: "100%",
        width: "100%",
        background: "rgba(0,0,0,0.6)"
      }}
    >
      <button onClick={() => alert("Clicked on Modal")}>Click</button>
    </div>,
    document.body
  );
}

function Dropdown(props) {
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const dropdownRef = React.useRef(null);
  onClickOutsideHook(dropdownRef, props.onClose);

  return (
    <div ref={dropdownRef}>
      Click outside and I will close
      <button onClick={() => setIsModalOpen(true)}>open Modal</button>
      {isModalOpen ? <Modal /> : <></>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem is when I click on the `Modal` button to trigger the alert, the `Dropdown` is closed before since I clicked outside of it (`Modal` is not rendered as a children of `Dropdown` but in `body`). So my alert is never triggered.

Is there a way to define `Modal` as a children of `Dropdown` using `ref` but still render it in `body` using `ReactDOM.createPortal`?

Just have a look to the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-feather-hw48n?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the [Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html#event-bubbling-through-portals) docs says:

> Even though a portal can be anywhere in the DOM tree, it behaves like a normal React child in every other way
> ...
>
> This includes event bubbling. An event fired from inside a portal will
> propagate to ancestors in the containing React tree, even if those
> elements are not ancestors in the DOM tree.

But here is not the case, the **mousedown** event listener was added on the **document** and not only the **Dropdown** component. Even so, the bubbling still happens.

This means that if you add a **ref** to the **Modal**, and then add an event listener on the **mousedown** event with the whole purpose to stop the propagation, the **handleClickOutside** function will never be called.

It may still seem like a workaround, I don't know if there is a proper way to check.

```
function Modal() {
  const modalRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const stopPropagation = e => {
      e.stopPropagation();
    };

    const { current: modalDom } = modalRef;
    modalDom.addEventListener("mousedown", stopPropagation);

    return () => {
      modalDom.removeEventListener("mousedown", stopPropagation);
    };
  }, []);

  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <div
      ref={modalRef}
      style={{
        position: "absolute",
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        height: "100%",
        width: "100%",
        background: "rgba(0,0,0,0.6)"
      }}
    >
      <button onClick={() => alert("Clicked on Modal")}>Click</button>
    </div>,
    document.body
  );
}
```

Watch the Modal component from the following [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-butterfly-w5wqb?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Thanks for your help it works perfectly and it's a nice workaround since it just impact the `Modal` component   Will wait a little bit to approve this answer but you deserve the bounty

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround you can add an ID attribute to your modal and then check if the click was outside the modal

```
function Modal() {
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <div id="modalId">
      <button onClick={() => alert("Clicked on Modal")}>Click</button>
    </div>,
    document.body
  );
}
```

```
...
React.useEffect(() => {
  const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
    if (
      ref?.current &&
      !ref.current.contains(event.target) &&
      document.getElementById("modalId") &&
      !document.getElementById("modalId").contains(event.target) // check if click was outside your modal
    ) {
      callback();
    }
  };
  // Bind the event listener
  document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
  return () => {
    // Unbind the event listener on clean up
    document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
  };
}, [callback, ref]);
...
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the idea but yeah as you said it's just a workaround ;) Upvote for the effort