# Hide div when clicked outside the child div in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, toggle, show-hide

I want to hide child div when clicked outside the child div. Toggle button should also work in this case.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Toggle() {
  const [view, setView] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div style={{ height: "100vh", backgroundColor: "lightblue" }}>
     
      <button onClick={() => setView(!view)}> show/hide </button>
    
      <div 
        style={{
          display: `${view ? "block" : "none"}`,
          height: "20vh",
          width: "10vw",
          backgroundColor: "lightcoral",
        }}
      >
        Child Div
      </div>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You can check the updated, 2021 answer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553158/detect-click-outside-react-component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is by getting the **mouse cursor coordinates on click** *(using the event)* and then adding a conditional statement to `setView` to **false** only if the cursor is outside the child div and the `view` is true.

```
export default function Toggle() {

const [view, setView] = useState(false);

  function hide(e) {
    if (e.pageX > 80 || e.pageY > 125) {
      if (view) setView(false);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div
      onClick={() => hide(event)}
      style={{ height: "100vh", backgroundColor: "lightblue" }}
    >
      <button onClick={() => setView(!view)}> show/hide </button>

      <div
        style={{
          display: `${view ? "block" : "none"}`,
          height: "20vh",
          width: "10vw",
          backgroundColor: "lightcoral"
        }}
      >
        Child Div
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: That's great, remember to vote up and check the answer.