# Swiper not fire document click through slide (example on React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

There is a global document click event(React hook useClickAway). But when you click on a slide, the event does not fire About example: circle in header, like avatar dropdown, click on it trigger menu. Menu closes if you click anywhere outside. How to close menu without hacks, when click to swiper slide too?
[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-snow-qeio3z)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32795201/3597730

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect click outside React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553158/detect-click-outside-react-component)

Comment: @ruby_newbie Click outside works fine, but if you click to swiper slide, event is not fire. The click event stops and does not reach the document

Comment: Please add the solution in the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prop `touchStartPreventDefault={false}` is solution

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `allowTouchMove` prop to `false` in your swiper settings.

By default, the prop is set to `true` to allow the movement of swiper slides by dragging and preventing any other unwanted click propagation making document clicks not fire.

Changing it to `false` may prevent dragging to move the swiper slide but it solves the issue. Check docs [here](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-allowTouchMove)