# How to prevent child with `position: absolute` from triggering `onBlur` event of parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a container that has two children: an input field and another `div` element that conditionally renders depending on the value for `isActive`. The problem that I'm running into is that whenever I click on the child `div`, then `onBlur` is triggered.

How can I prevent this from happening? I've already tried `e.stopPropagation()` as you can see below. Also, I've tried moving `onBlur` and `onFocus` to the container `div`, but that didn't work either.

[image: pensive-forest-ksmi2o]

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClick = React.useCallback((e) => {
    e.stopPropagation(); // does not work
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      className="container"
      onFocus={() => setIsActive(true)}
      onBlur={() => setIsActive(false)}
    >
      <input />
      {isActive && <div className="child" onClick={handleClick} />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This example is the best solution to the problem
[Detect click outside React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553158/detect-click-outside-react-component)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `onBlur` handler on the input element is triggered every time the user clicks outside it. So using `onBlur` event listener may not be the solution.

If you are only interested in keeping the child `div` visible when the user clicks it, I propose to add a click event listener to the `document`, which when called, check whether the event target is inside the container `div`(parent of the `input` and child `div`) and hide the child `div` accordingly.

```
export default function App() {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
  const container = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = (event) => {
      if (!container.current.contains(event.target)) {
        setIsActive(false);
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("click", handler);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("click", handler);
    };
  });

  return (
    <div className="container" ref={ctn}>
      <input className="input" onFocus={() => setIsActive(true)} />
      {isActive && <div className="child" />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit hungry-rain-qmt75l]

This solution will not work if you really care about the focus state of the input element. The user can move focus with tab.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the fix [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-orla-mdfsgq?file=/src/App.js:156-705)

**Explanation**

```
{isActive && <div className="child" onClick={handleClick} />}
```

`handleClick` here does not help for you, because it never gets triggered due to re-rendering, so that's why `e.stopPropagation()` is not working for your case.

Another problem is `onFocus` and `onBlur` are only applied for [activable element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement), so it means these events happen on `input` field (not `div`). You can try to replace `input` with another `div` for the experiment.

So how to make `div` become activable element? Well, you just simply put [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) for `div`. Your code will work properly

> The tabindex global attribute indicates that its element can be focused

```
<div
      className="container"
      tabindex="100" //add tabindex here
      onFocus={() => setIsActive(true)}
      onBlur={(e) => {
        const currentTarget = e.currentTarget;

        // Give browser time to focus the next element
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
          // Check if the new focused element is a child of the original container
          if (!currentTarget.contains(document.activeElement)) {
            setIsActive(false);
          }
        });
      }}
    >
      <input />
      {isActive && <div className="child" />}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I tried about a dozen solutions but none worked with my absolute-positioned element (a floating menu). This does.