# How to close multiple dropdown in reactjs when click outside

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, dropdown

```
I create custom dropdowns and handle through states in react.js
I used the below link code when I apply for two dropdowns then it's not working 
When I apply on two dropdowns the 2nd dropdown value is changed and 1st dropdown value is not changeable
```

This is working on single dropdown but in multiple dropdown not working
How to close multiple dropdowns when clicking outside in reactjs

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553158/detect-click-outside-react-component](https://%20%20%20%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553158/detect-click-outside-react-component)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it is difficult to determine how to answer your question.

Your dropdowns are presumably controlled by state within the component.
Something like this?

```js
const Dropdown = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  ...
}
```

Then you have a parent component rendering the dropdowns.

```js
const Parent = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Dropdown />
      <Dropdown />
    </>
  )
}
```

Since the state is held within the components, we can't modify both at once. The solution is to lift state.

```js
const Dropdown = ({ open }) => {

  ...
}

const Parent = () => {
  const [openDropdowns, setOpenDropdowns] = useState({});
}
```