# React event order

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu

Full reproduction:  [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/evet-order-execution-rkklvn?file=/src/App.js) .

I am trying to create a custom search/select component with react. My problem lies in execution order of events.

When a user focuses in on the text input field, a list with options should be shown. Then when the user clicks on one of the items in the dropdown, the element name should be filled in the text input field and then the list should be hidden.

I achive this by creating a `inputFocused` boolean state, and rendering list only when `inputFocused` is true. I attach twop event handlers on the text input itself:

- ```
  onFocus={() => setInputFocused(true)}
  ```
- ```
  onBlur={() => setInputFocused(false)}
  ```

But when a user clicks on one of the items, input is not getting filled.

```
<input
   value={searchTerm}
   onChange={(e) => {
     setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
   }}
   onBlur={() => setInputFocused(false)}
   onFocus={() => setInputFocused(true)}
/>
```

```
{inputFocused && (
    <ul>
        <li onClick={() => setSearchTerm(element.name)}>{element.name}</li>
    </ul>
}
```

Check codesanbox link for better understanding.

I think i understand the problem. `onBlur()` event triggers before the `onClick()` event. If i wrap the onBlur callback function inside a setTimout, it will work  as expected:

```
onBlur={() =>
    setTimeout(() => {
        setInputFocused(false);
    }, 100) 
}
```

I would like to avoid defining a setTimeout.

Is there solution to make sure that `onClick()` on `<li>` executes before `onBlur()` on `<input />` ?

Comment: You can experiment with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553158/detect-click-outside-react-component but I guess it won't work with keyboard so well

Comment: I have tried that as well. Same problem. https://codesandbox.io/s/evet-order-execution-forked-bjkt1y?file=/src/App.js .

Comment: I’m currently trying a similar code and it seems that indeed for some reason onBlur event in the parent fires before onClick event in children, it seems that you can use onPointerDown in children to avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `onClick` to `onMouseDown` on the list items, and the ordering will be handled properly by the browser.

The events get fired in the order of mousedown -> mouseup -> click (see
https://javascript.info/mouse-events-basics#events-order)

Comment: Thank you, that did help. Although, this introcuded problems with `mouseDown()` capturing not only left mouse clicks, but also a middle mouse click, etc, but anyway that did answer my question!

Comment: ah ok, you can check `event.button` if you want to ignore or only respond to certain click types
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event

Comment: How are you handling keyboard events? onKeyPress? I wish there was a link in react docs explaining how the event order works.