# how to make toggle if user click element window toggle take value false ? in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

i make toogle in react using useState like this sample component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const Button = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    function listing () {
      setShow(false)
  }
    if (show && true) {
      window.addEventListener("click", listing, true)
      console.log("test")
    }
  })
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() =>
        setShow(true)
      }>
      test
      </button>
      {show && <div> show text</div>}
    </>
  )
}
export default Button
```

but if button already true value and im click again button value is true and im click window element be false, so element target div show cant gone, but is same if im give  **setShow(!show)** on listener onclick button. target element keep show if already true

Comment: `else { window.removeEventListener("click", listing) }`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is something that you want to create:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
export const Button = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  return (
      <button onClick={() => setShow(!show)}>
       {show ? "active" : "inactive" }
      </button>

  );
};
```

Comment: but if button active and user click other window or screen button become inactive

Comment: like dropdown in navigation or sometimes user choice language so user can have thow choice inactive button , click screen or click button

Comment: you can see this article about a hook called useOutSideClick
 
https://usehooks.com/useOnClickOutside/

Comment: thank you for reference article , im already find anwer

Answer (score 0):

im find answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45323523/16945930

and i add liltle code

```
import React,{ useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

 function useComponentVisible(initialIsVisible) {
    const [isComponentVisible, setIsComponentVisible] = useState(initialIsVisible);
    const ref = useRef(null);

    const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
        if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
            setIsComponentVisible(false);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('click', handleClickOutside, true);
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('click', handleClickOutside, true);
        };
    }, []);

    return { ref, isComponentVisible, setIsComponentVisible };
}

const DropDown = () => {
  const { ref, isComponentVisible, setIsComponentVisible } = useComponentVisible(false);
  return (
    <>
  
     <div ref={ref}>
      <a onClick={()=> {setIsComponentVisible(!isComponentVisible)}}>show</a>
        {isComponentVisible && (<p>Dropdown Component</p>)}
     </div>
     </>
  );

}
export default DropDown
```