# Existing toggle should close when click another toggle in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

How we can manage parent and child component ?

There are three dropdown button , its show hide itself based of click , but I want to close existing opened dropdown when we client next dropdown

```
//Parent child 
const Parent = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <div> A- click me <Dropdown props={} /></div>
            <div> B - click me <Dropdown props={} /></div>
            <div> C- click me<Dropdown props={} /></div>
        </>
    )
}
export default Parent;



//Dropdown component
const Dropdown = (props) => {
    const onOffFn = () => {
        setOnOff(!onOff);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <div onClick={onOffFn} > button </div>
                {onOff ? <div> Content </div> : null}
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Dropdown;
```

If Already open A dropwndown, then it should close when I click other dropdown, How is it possible

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is `Dropdown` ? Is it a component you've created or is it from some kind of UI library ?

Comment: Sorry for my typo mistake , updated question  , Dropdown means just child component @Titus

Comment: You can keep the state of all dropdowns in the parent or you can implement a click outside effect like the first example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42234988/1552587)